# Is there a way to list all aliases in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, command-line, path

I would like to know if it  is possible to have a list of all aliases in windows, like the command:

`Get-Alias`

but that shows all aliases that are usable, for example `python3` or `jupyter-notebook`

Thanks!

Comment: Not really, it's not like PowerShell knows what utilities, programs, etc. that are installed, and what's not. The only thing I can think of, is listing the executables found in the Environment Path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`python3` and `jupyter-notebook` are not aliases, they are applications, available in the search path. Aliases are a PowerShell construct and only exist within PowerShell.

But if what you're really asking is how you can list all possible *commands* (which includes: cmdlets, functions, aliases, applications, external scripts), then you can use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-5.1).

By default, it will not show applications, but you can tell it explicitly to return all types of commands with a wildcard in the `-Name` parameter:

```
Get-Command -Name *
```

You can also specify specific type(s) you want to see:

```
Get-Command -Type Application
Get-Command -Type Alias
Get-Command -Type Cmdlet,Application
```

If you want to group them to see how many of each type:

```
Get-Command -Name * | Group-Object -Property CommandType
```